# Run powershell script on multiple servers parallelly

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

Probably a repetitive question, but need some to-the-point answers as I'm still learning. I want to run the PowerShell script on all remote servers- simultaneously, to install an application. I tried the below cmdlet but it's executing one after the other, and also would like to know the status or job output file. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

```
$servers = Get-Content "C:\Dumps\Scripts\servers.txt"

foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Filepath C:\Dumps\Scripts\CompleteSilent.ps1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `$Servers` as the `-ComputerName` argument. `Invoke-Command` will run them parallel.

You can adjust the Throttle on the parallelism with the `-Throttle` parameter.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servers -Filepath C:\Dumps\Scripts\CompleteSilent.ps1
```

Note: If there are return objects and or screen echoes they may return disordered. It can be handled, but if this is an installation you may not encounter that particular issue.

Comment: Thanks Is it possible to capture installation status into a log file? PS script contains java and tomcat silent install cmds.

Comment: That really depends.  If the installer creates a log it'll be independent of the PowerShell command.  You'll likely have to handle by copying somewhere...